# How to capture memo text to edit Delphi

Tags: delphi, wildcard, delphi-7, tmemo

I would like to capture dynamic gateway IP populated in a memo to a text box.
How can I do it with either wildcards or capture the whole line of gateway that starts with "Gateway: 10.127.*.*" and get the gateway IP to the text box.

Here is the example of memo text already captured:

```
Description: Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
HW Address Length: 6
HWAddress: E0:2A:82:F9:B2:3E
Index: 32
Type: 71
CurrentIPAddress: 
IP Addresses:    192.168.48.1/255.255.255.0
Gateway:    0.0.0.0/255.255.255.255
Name: {22712B8F-5E3A-48D4-8C0D-771708BF0305}
Description: HUAWEI Mobile Connect - Network Card
HW Address Length: 6
HWAddress: 0C:5B:8F:27:9A:64
Index: 4
Type: 243
CurrentIPAddress: 
IP Addresses:    10.127.144.193/255.255.255.252
Gateway:    10.127.144.194/255.255.255.255
```

EDIT: (from Comment)

```
I:= Pos('Gateway: 10.127.', Memo1.Text);
if I > 0 then begin
   L := SendMessage(Memo1.Handle, EM_LINEFROMCHAR,   (intTostr(1));
   edit1.Text:=(intTostr(L));
```

Comment: What version of Delphi? Recent versions support regular expressions that can be used to help here; earlier versions don't.

Comment: What part of this do you find challenging? Why are you using a GUI control for text processing? What does your code look like? Are you hoping we will write your code for you?

Comment: i have a sample code but only gets me line number

Comment: `I:= Pos('Gateway:    10.127.', Memo1.Text);
  if I > 0 then begin
    L := SendMessage(Memo1.Handle, EM_LINEFROMCHAR,(intTostr(1);
    edit1.Text:=(intTostr(L));`

Comment: There appear to be 3 spaces following the `:`. And why on earth are you using `EM_LINEFROMCHAR`? That's insane. You are text processing. No place for GUI controls. Do you know how to debug your code? If not then everything else is pointless. Stop what you are doing and learn to debug.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Delphi 7 version of René's answer:

```
var
  ii: integer
begin
  for ii := 0 to memo.lines.count -1 do begin
    if pos('Gateway:   10.127.', memo.lines[ii]) > 0 then begin
      textbox.caption := memo.lines[ii];
      break; 
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thanks  a lot @Micheal Vicent it works well its capture 
How do i remove the Gateway:    word and only remain with the result at
`10.127.`

Comment: @JkRobbin How do you think it would be done? Have you really given up all hope of solving this yourself? This is simple text processing. Don't ask new questions in comments. Why not find a tutorial or text book or even the documentation. Surely you aren't the first person to want to extract a substring? Are you sure you can't work this out for yourself? I know I sound harsh, but you are simply not trying hard enough, and this site is not intended to teach novices how to do basic tasks. Please visit the [help]. We are here to build a resource of Q&A posts that will be useful to future visitors.

Comment: only for completeness :You can not trust the spaces or signs in a created and captured text ! Here is, not 100 %, but better : `if pos('GATEWAY:10.127.', UpperCase(StringReplace(Memo1.lines[ii],' ','',[rfReplaceAll]))) > 0 then`

Comment: @moskito - nice addition. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Easist way to achieve this would be to iterate over the memo's lines and check if it begins with "Gateway:    10.127.".

For example:

```
for LString in memo.Lines do
  if AnsiStartsText('Gateway:    10.127.', LString) then
    textbox.Caption := LString
```

You could use regular expressions as well for more specific handling.

Comment: Delphi 7 doesn't have the for .. in loop, nor regular expressions that were suggested as possibly helping.  You'll need to use a for loop with an index, a bit like:  for I := 0 to memo.lines.count -1 do